# Столбчатая диаграмма Py Qt 5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Необходимо отфильтровать данные и построить столбчатую диаграмму. Есть несколько типов оборудования, на каждом из которых пользователь может совершать определенные операции (например, станок №1, за которым работают Вася и Петя, которые могут сверлить отверстия или резать материал). На вход подаются данные следующего вида:

1. data_1, data_2 - начальная и конечные даты фильтрации
2. Список пользователей users
3. Список оборудования для фильтрации machines

Нужно построить данные по операциям в виде столбчатой диаграммы примерно такого вида, где каждый столбик соответствует определенной машине (в примере с Васей и Петей нужно получить изображение периодов времени, например, за месяц, в которые выполнялось резание или сверление за станком №1).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При кликании на столбик появлялась бы новая диаграмма, имеющая такую же структуру, но уже для каждого пользователя отображались бы операции относительно времени (каждый столбик соотв. определенному пользователю). В примере с Васей и Петей было бы два столбика, каждый из которых показывал периоды времени, в  которые производилось сверление или резание Васей (столбик №1) или Петей (столбик №2).
Я пытался использовать `QPercentBarSeries`, но не очень понятно, как делать "отступы" между операциями белым цветом, т.е. как создать помимо "Operation 1", "Operation 2" еще и " No operation" и задать для него белый цвет. Так же я искал как при нажатии на столбик вывести другой виджет, но не смог найти подходящий решений.
Вот что я  пытался использовать:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QBarSet, QPercentBarSeries, QBarCategoryAxis
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt



class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt BarChart")
        self.setGeometry(100,100, 680,500)
        self.show()
        self.create_bar()




    def create_bar(self):
        #The QBarSet class represents a set of bars in the bar chart.
         # It groups several bars into a bar set

        set0 = QBarSet("Operation1")
        set1 = QBarSet("Operation2")
        set2 = QBarSet("Operation3")
        set3 = QBarSet("Operation4")
        set4 = QBarSet("Operation5")

        set0 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6
        set1 << 5 << 0 << 0 << 4 << 0 << 7
        set2 << 3 << 5 << 8 << 13 << 8 << 5
        set3 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 3 << 4 << 5
        set4 << 9 << 7 << 5 << 3 << 1 << 2

        series = QPercentBarSeries()
        series.append(set0)
        series.append(set1)
        series.append(set2)
        series.append(set3)
        series.append(set4)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Percent Example")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        categories = ["Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3", "Machine4", "Machine5", "Machine6"]
        axis = QBarCategoryAxis()
        axis.append(categories)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAxisX(axis, series)

        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)





App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```